# Java 7 Calendar.getInstance, TimeZone.getTimeZone got synchronized and slow, any work arounds?

Tags: java, performance, synchronized, simpledateformat

After upgrading my runtime to Java 7 I see incredible slowness... and my program is spending all of its time in the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor.  As described in a great post here: http://coffeedriven.org/?p=83 the `TimeZone` code is now checking for the presence of an application context in the `static synchronized` method `getDefaultInAppContext()`.

The problem for me is that it's [Spring Batch](https://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) file reader code that is creating a `new SimpleDateFormat` object for each line that it reads!

Anyone got a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this by making a change to Spring Batch itself.  For now the change is in a local copy but I've entered a Jira issue and hope to contribute our fix back to Spring Batch itself.

The change itself is to change the use of SimpleDateFormat from a member variable to an injected one (which seems more Spring-like anyway).  This lets us control its lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat` has always been slow, now I learn that it is even slower in `Java 7`.

Like @MK we also cache them. But note that it is not *threadsafe*. We ended up creating `ThreadLocals`.

[`JodaTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is highly recommended, though I have never used it and I don't know it has date formatting

Comment: The problem is that I'm using Spring Batch and the date format call is in there so I can't change to JodaTime myself.

Comment: You may be able to use `AspectJ` to deploy a production aspect to use `JodaTime` instead of `SimpleDateFormat` or just to use cached `SimpleDateFormat` objects

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to report that this was fixed in [JDK-8074002](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8074002) which ships in Java 9. It's now down to a `#clone()`.

Answer (score -1):

Joda Time is the best Date Time API for date-time calculations. Remember that if your requirements need a different time zone, you should use the JodaTime API.

Comment: "must" is too strong a word here. I certainly agree that Joda Time is a much nicer API, but it's not like the standard libraries don't support different time zones.

Comment: @JonSkeet; I doesn't mean that std. library is not capable but here i mean that in JOda Time API is having lots of build in extended function for ease and time saving. Sorry for my work "must". :)