# java TimeZone getDefault is very slow?

Tags: java, timezone

I'm using the call TimeZone.getDefault frequently, and I've got reports on slowness from my customers. Checking the threads stack trace using jstack, I see that many threads are blocked on this method:

```
"LoadBalancerClientSubscriber(7)" prio=10 tid=0x00000000010c2000 nid=0x4055 runnable     [0x00002aaaebc79000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultInAppContext(TimeZone.java:734)
    - locked <0x0000000512916db0> (a java.lang.Class for java.util.TimeZone)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultRef(TimeZone.java:630)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDefault(TimeZone.java:622)
"RequestServiceThreadPool(5)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaae01b2800 nid=0x4022 waiting for     monitor entry [0x00002aaae8a47000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultInAppContext(TimeZone.java:734)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000512916db0> (a java.lang.Class for java.util.TimeZone)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultRef(TimeZone.java:630)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDefault(TimeZone.java:622)
```

Is this a known behavior? Should I cache this TimeZone object? Is it safe to cache it, if my app is running for many months (even during DST change)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code if `TimeZone.getDefault`? You can find it in `src.zip` in your JDK installation directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 7 Calendar.getInstance, TimeZone.getTimeZone got synchronized and slow, any work arounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984345/java-7-calendar-getinstance-timezone-gettimezone-got-synchronized-and-slow-any)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a known issue: http://coffeedriven.org/2012/10/14/be-carefull-with-calendar-getinstance-and-timezone-gettimezone/

The easy workaround is to call the method once and cache the result.

Comment: Thanks. Is it safe to cache the results even for months? The timezone object does not change on DST switch?